# Adding different list items to array of unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three unordered lists that have the same class. I loop through them and I'm trying to add items that match certain descriptions to each of them, but when I try to reference the list by its index, it says it can't find the append function. The code looks something like this:

```
demoTypes.upcomingDemos.map(function(item) {
    var itemElement = "<li>My Item</li>";
    if (demoTypes.type == "Basic") {
        $(".unorderedListSection")[0].append(itemElement);
    } else if (demoTypes.type == "Intermediate") {
        $(".unorderedListSection")[1].append(itemElement);
    } else if (demoTypes.type == "Advanced") {
        $(".unorderedListSection")[2].append(itemElement);
    }

});
```

Adding the items to ALL the lists seems to work fine for some reason (although I obviously don't want to do this):

```
$(".unorderedListSection").append(itemElement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When accessing a jQuery object by index it returns a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, hence you get the error about the lack of an `append()` method.

To fix this, use the `eq()` method:

```
demoTypes.upcomingDemos.map(function(item) {
    var itemElement = "<li>My Item</li>";
    if (demoTypes.type == "Basic") {
        $(".unorderedListSection").eq(0).append(itemElement);
    } else if (demoTypes.type == "Intermediate") {
        $(".unorderedListSection").eq(1).append(itemElement);
    } else if (demoTypes.type == "Advanced") {
        $(".unorderedListSection").eq(2).append(itemElement);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function returns an object which is a wrapper around an array of elements. When you access an item at a given index (`$(selector)[index]`) you no longer have a jQuery object but a raw element.

```js
console.log($('p').html());
console.log($('p')[0].toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
```

Instead, you can use the [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get an element at an index wrapped in a jQuery object.

```js
console.log($('p').eq(0).html());
console.log($('p').eq(1).html());
console.log($('p').eq(2).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
```